# Convert from String to date

Tags: java, date

I want to convert a string like "2012-03-08T00:00:00+01:00" into Date..

I tried to use Dateformatter with "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm" but it doesn't work (error while parsing).

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Is the source under your control? If it is, you might want to use timestamps.. they will offer you much better control

Comment: But your pattern doesn't match the date format ! Where is the T, where are seconds ? and timezone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern should match : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ